# Having trouble with using C++ library in C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

So I'm writing this program that uses a 3rd party DLL written in C++. I'd like to write the program in C#, since I know a thing or two about the language and I never did anything in C++.
I got the library called CIUsbLib in a pack of files: .dll, .h, .lib, .ext. The program is meant for a target computer (Win7 32bit), different to what I'm developing on (Win10 and Win8 both 64bit) - I have limited access to target computer. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and according to VS's Object Browser the DLL contains some classes with several methods I want to use.
I found there are three methods available - reference the library in the C# project, P/Invoke (using DllImport) and C++/CLI wrapper.

So I first tried referencing the library in my C# project, but it directly crashes on instantiating the class on both dev computers and throws AccessViolationException on the target computer. I wasn't able to figure out why it's happening but I blamed it on the library's code being unmanaged.

After doing some research I found that DllImport can't be used on methods closed in a class. So I tried the C++/CLI wrapper, but soon realized that referencing the C++ library in Visual C++ CLR project adds "Interop.CIUsbLib.1.0.dll" library to references, which apparently is managed. At

```
namespace CIUsbLib_wrap
{

public ref class CIUsbLib_wrapper
{
    CHostDrv* wrap_class;
public:
    CIUsbLib_wrapper() { wrap_class = new CHostDrv};

};
}
```

Visual Studio shows error on the asterisk, saying the class already is C++/CLI. Obviously I'm trying to wrap an already wrapped library. Does VS automatically create an implicit wrapper, preventing me from writing my own?

After I tried this I noticed the library contents are different when viewed in VS's Object Browser in CLR project:
[DLL in CLR project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeFP7.png)
and when viewed in C# project:
[DLL in C# project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Erinp.png).
In the first picture, CHostDrv and IHostDrv are interface classes and CHostDrvClass is ref class; in the other picture, CHostDrv is interface and CHostDrv is class. I don't understand, why is it different?

So I see two ways to find a solution:

- Find out why instantiating the library's class throws an AccessViolationException on the target computer and crashes the program on other computers
- Create wrapper for CIUsbLib.dll and not for Interop.CIUsbLib.1.0.dll
- Something else?

Any help is welcome here, because if I don't find a solution I'll have to write the program in C++ and that really sucks for me.

Comment: You get an Interop.xyz.dll file when the DLL contains a type library and implements a COM server.  The other way to interop with native code that you did not list.  No wrapper is required, you can use it directly from C#.  You are wasting a lot of time on this, clearly you need to use a telephone.  Talk to the author, ask for a manual and a code sample, have a small repro project ready so he can tell what the underlying problem might be.  If nobody picks up then don't use it.

Comment: Okay thanks, I contacted the author and got new version of the library, which works fine.